# Jquery-Enviar Post para salvar no banco de dados

Tags: php, jquery

Estou desenvouvendo um site que pega os dados de um determinado local e ao clicar no botão ele tem que salvar em outro lugar e para isso estou usando Jquery porem n estou conseguindo salvar no meu banco alguem pode me ajudar.

codigo que tras o conteudo

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON("myonsala", function(result){
            $("form div.online").empty();
                $.each(result, function(i, field){


                    $("form div.online").append("<div class=\"user impar\">" + "<figure>" + "<img src=\"img/users/Profiles/"+field.foto+"\">" + 
                    "</figure>"+"<span class=\"nickname\">"+field.Ninck +"<span class=\"cartaoAmarelo cartaoAmarelo0\">"+"</span>"
                    +"</span>"+"<p class=\"desafiar\" onclick=\"desafio();\">"+" DESAFIAR!"+"<input  name=\"desafiado\" type=\"hidden\" value="+field.Id+">"+
                    " </p>"+ "</div>");

            });
            $("span#onsala").empty();  
            $("span#onsala").append(result.length);

        });
});
```

else tem que pegar o valor que vai vim do campo `desafiado` e enviar para pagina php para isso.

pagina php:

```
      if(isset($_POST['desafiado'])){
            if(isset($_SESSION['sala'])){
                if(isset($_SESSION['tkm'])){
                    $desafiado = $_POST['desafiado'];
                    //$desafiado=16;
                    $sala=$_SESSION['sala'];
                    $tkm=$_SESSION['tkm'];
                    $results = DB::select("SELECT Id,Ninck FROM usuarios WHERE Has='$tkm'");
                    foreach($results as $row){
                        $Id=$row->Id;
                        $Nick=$row->Ninck;
                    }
                    $results = DB::select("SELECT Ninck FROM usuarios WHERE Id='$desafiado'");
                    foreach($results as $row){  
                        $Nickop=$row->Ninck;
                    }
                    $results = DB::select("SELECT s.Valor as valors FROM onsalas o,salas s WHERE o.Idsala=s.Id");
                    foreach($results as $row){  
                        $valor=$row->valors;
                    }
                    //dd($valor);
                    $cron = '02:40';
                    $date =date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                    $datec = date('Y-m-d');
                    $horac= date('H:i:s');
                    $inserir= DB::table('Partidas')->insert(
                        ['IdDesafiante'=>$Id,'NickDesafiante'=>$Nick,'IdDesafiado'=>$desafiado,'NickDesafiado'=>$Nickop,'Aceitou'=>0,'CronDesafiante'=>$cron,'CronDesafiado'=>$cron,'Valor'=>$valor,'IdSala'=>$sala,'CanceladoPreJogo'=>0,'IdCanceladorPreJogo'=>0,'Motivo'=>0,'AbamdonarPartida'=>0,'IdAbandonarPartida'=>0,'Divegencia'=>0,'DataCriacao'=>$datec,'HoraCriacao'=>$horac,'HoraAceito'=>0,'HoraFimPrejogo'=>0,'HoraFinal'=>0,'updated_at'=>$date,'created_at'=>$date]    
                    );
                    dd($inserir);
                    $banco='f';
                    return response()->json($banco); 
                }else{
                    echo "erro1";
                }
            }else{
                echo "erro3";
            }           
        }else{
            echo "erro3";
        }
```

Alguem pode me ajudar. estou usando o jquery pq n posso dar submit na pagina pois n quero q ela recarregue

update dia 16/07/2018
utilisando ajax

```
function desafio(){
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var data=$(this).serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
     url: "desafio",
     type: "post",
     dataType: "json",
     data: data,   
   })
   .done(function() {
     alert( "success" );
   })
   .fail(function() {
     alert( "error" );
   })
   .always(function() {

   });
})
```

}

agora ele da o supmit porem como GET e na pagina q estou n na pagina que coloquei para ela ir

Comment: Você pode utilizar o Ajax para realizar tal procedimento ou se preferir o axios
Abaixo segue link das duas documentações:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

https://github.com/axios/axios

Comment: @LucasBrogni, funcionou obrigado, porem agora ele esta submetendo  a pagina e n queria qu isso acontecedde teria como efitar isso ?

Comment: você está utilizando o ajax ou o axios?

Comment: @LucasBrogni estou utilisando. vou atualizar o post para mostrar

Comment: remove o submit --> $('form').submit(function(e)

Comment: @LucasBrogni ainda esta dando submit